# Get and Set Checkbox properties, using checkbox names as strings

Tags: c#

On a windows form, there are a group of checkboxes, chx1, chx2, chx3....chx20.

I need to loop through 1-20 and set the Checked property of these checkboxes.  Is there a function that would accept the checkbox name as a string, the property to get or set as a string, and the value to set the property)?

Set:

```
GetSetProperty("chx1", "Checked", true);
```

or

Get:

```
GetSetProperty("chx1", "Checked");
```

Comment: Please elaborate on this. Why not just use this: `foreach(var cb in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()) cb.Checked = true;`?

Comment: I am creating a set of checklist that users must complete.  Based on database values, I need to set the items that have been marked complete.  For instance, each numeric value(1-20) is either complete or not complete(1 - true, 2 - false, 3 - true, etc.)  It is not a good option for this application to bind these checkboxes to a dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
((CheckBox)this.Controls["checkBox1"]).Checked = true;
```

Try something along the lines of this.

Comment: Wanted to give this answer, i'm too slow :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to do exactly what you're talking about, but it's easier (IMO) and faster to just put the checkboxes in an array and use the index to find/manipulate them. If you do this though, be careful, because your checkboxes are indexed from one while arrays are indexed from zero, so you'll have to account for the one-off difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to perform this and it will build the list of items checked or not checked (you can also do a foreach and check or uncheck them all.

```
var checkedBoxList = container.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault(
r => r.Checked);

foreach(CheckBox chkbox in CheckedBoxList)
{ chkbox.Checked = false;}
```

The container should be what hosts all the controls. You could set this as your form and it will get all of them or you can select the specific groupbox/panel.